# GCP Cloud run - how do I get CloudRun service parameters run-time

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have several CloudRun services running. I have the need to do some environment specific things (also because I have a docker container being built from the same sources too) in code. I searched around quite a bit to find out if I can get the following run-time:

1. Check if my code is running in a CloudRun instance or not
2. Get other environment variables like service-name, project-name, deploy-time, awake-time, region-name, etc. - for various reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This demo container code shows how to get that kind of information:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-run-hello/blob/master/hello.go

Some things are available directly as environment variables like service and revision

```
    service := os.Getenv("K_SERVICE")
    revision := os.Getenv("K_REVISION")
```

The container contract docs page shows the full list
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract

as well as information about the metadata server that can give you things like project-id or region.